# How to hide video element for browsers without safari

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari

Could you please help me? I need to add video tag to HTML page for safari browser and block\hide it for others. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function browserHasName(name){  
   var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();  
   if (agent.indexOf(name.toLowerCase())>-1) {  
     return true;  
   }  
   return false;  
}  

if( browserHasName('safari') ) {
   //add video to DOM 

   // using plain javascript
   document.write('<video><source src="yourVideoPath.mp4" /></video>'); 


   //using jquery (personal recommendation)
   $('body').append('<video><source src="yourVideoPath.mp4" /></video>');
}


//or


if(!browserHasName('safari') ) {
   //remove video from DOM
}
```

Comment: //add video to DOM... How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to hide it for ALL other browsers? you should generaly use [feature detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh475813.aspx) and allow any browser with the capabilities to play the video.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp